# PHP global arrays... embedded in html

Tags: php

Ugh.. so I have a form when completed it will take you to the url

`wiki.php?msg=succesfull`

but I dont want people to go directly there if they know the url, so I want to check if the user is the one who posted the new article.

This is how I get the ID of the user who posts an article

```
$AuthorID = $_SESSION['user_ID'];
```

So I have this message in HTML that shows like "succesfull posted", and I tried this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == "article-creation-success" && $_SESSION['user_ID'] == $_POST['postuser_ID']): ?>
```

and this is what I have at the top, trying to create a global variable

```
$AuthorID = $_SESSION['user_ID'];
$postuser_ID = $_POST[$AuthorID];`
```

But I still get the error...:
`Undefined index: postuser_ID in`

Comment: I'm curious, what does the `:` do in the `if` statement?

Comment: And you're checking for `article-creation-success` as value for `$_GET['msg']` instead of `successfull`

Comment: This line `$postuser_ID = $_POST[$AuthorID];` seems dubious.

Comment: @Tesseract it's an alternate syntax for if statements in PHP

Comment: @Cfreak Oh, okay. I thought it was a typo

Comment: @Tesseract that kind of sums up the majority of PHP :)

Comment: Where do you get the value for `$_POST[$AuthorID]`?

Comment: No where... I was trying to assign $AuthorID to $_POST so I can use it globally.. because if I use $AuthorID embedded in html like <?php echo $AuthorID ?> it will tell me that the variable is undefined, I do not know how to make a document global variable...

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your html form

```
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo (issset($_SESSION['user_ID']) ? $_SESSION['user_ID'] : '') ?> name="postuser_ID" />
```

because it says you  not passing postuser_ID in your form

Answer (score 0):

error is present on this line, you're trying to access `postuser_ID` key but not sending it from form.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == "article-creation-success" && $_SESSION['user_ID'] == $_POST['postuser_ID']): ?>
```